# Compound Words Vs Words with preposition "of"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

Why we can say:

**TV reporter**

but we can't say:

**reporter of TV**

This complex word is wrong in terms of lexis, meaning, or it's just ungrammatical?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **mistake**? But it is certainly possible to say "a reporter **on** TV" which is the same as a "TV reporter"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the "of".

Reporter of TV would be someone who reports about television. A TV reporter is a reporter who appears on TV.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean is a TV is a thing so we don't use "of TV" but "on TV" instead. As Nathan pointed out, you can make a thing possess something but it has to have an " 's".

"Online journalist" is another example - you would say "a journalist online" and not "a journalist of online."

Comment: "Who's that car's owner?" is perfectly reasonable. (And "online journalist" is not a problem either.)

Comment: I don't mean online journalist is a problem but was simply giving another example like "A tv reporter."

Comment: But you have to say a journalist online and not journalist of online. I'll edit my wording.